# Best way to quickly burn sugar

Tags: sugar

After you had an excess of sugar what is the best way to burn it to avoid accumulating it as fat?

Comment: Your question is far too general. First off all, you should probably try to limit your sugar intake so you don't have an excess. Second, any type of exercise would help burn energy, so what are you asking for?

Answer (score 3):

Same as any other way to burn energy - work out in the way that makes you happiest.

Comment: And how quickly would that need to happen to avoid accumulating sugar as fat?

Comment: @L.DeLeo The variables (age, metabolism, genetics, etc....) are numerous. This will vary with each individual.